# Firebase Performance Monitoring, Can't instrument...IllegalArgumentException

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I'm using `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'`

I applied the plugin: `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'`

and in my project level gradle: `classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'`

I'm running into a few issues. 
1) during my build, I see a lot of `Can't instrument` exceptions like this:

```
Can't instrument: kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClasses$1$enumMemberNames$1.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.InstrumentationVisitor.<init>(InstrumentationVisitor.java:55)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.Instrument.instrument(Instrument.java:170)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.Instrument.instrumentClassesInJar(Instrument.java:117)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfTransform.performTransformationFor(FirebasePerfTransform.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfTransform.transformJarInputs(FirebasePerfTransform.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfTransform.transform(FirebasePerfTransform.java:416)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at
```

2) I only see logging `TraceMetric` and no `NetworkRequestMetric`. the API calls are using Retrofit2, which uses OkHttp3

Comment: If the plugin isn't working the way you expect, open a bug report with Firebase support so they can investigate.  You will want to give very specific information about how you build and run your app, including code.  The first issue you show here is not likely a problem.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the fix was to move the classpath of the firebase performance before the other plugin that has the dependency to the "org.ow2.asm:asm"(in the project level gradle file).

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
    classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacoco_version"
    ...
 }
```

Firebase plugin uses version 7.0 of the org.ow2.asm:asm
Jacoco plugin uses 5.+ of the org.ow2.asm:asm

To check the versions you can try to use ./gradlew buildEnvironment

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/gradle/gradle/9650/499815877

Maybe you have the same issue as me.